Style a fullscreen slider for portrait and landscape images
How would I style a slider for mobile devices for landscape and portrait images where

all images are set up as a square image as either a pillerbox or a letterbox
the user is supposed to rotate the handheld to accomodate the aspect of either image type

I have an example site here specifically for a desktop sized browser but want to improve it to a handheld optimized version.

The slider works ok on my phone. What exactly would you like to improve?
